# In memory mongo database for unit tests in a private network

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, unit-testing, in-memory-database

I have a java/spring-boot/maven project that uses `Mongo` as database. I want to create some tests (unit tests and integration tests) for this project, that would run in a clean machine. To help with that, I started to look for in memory mongo database, that would be applicable only for unit tests.

I've found [Flapdoodle](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo), and it worked as expected in my local machine. I could run the tests I needed without having the whole Mongo setup. However, it downloads `EmbeddedMongo`, which is something that can't be done on the official build machine (Continuous integration), since it runs in a private network and it can't download it.

Since it tries to download `EmbeddedMongo` only on the first time, I thought - maybe if I manually place the folder `.embedmongo` on the build machine, it wouldn't need to download it from the unreachable server. So I tried to configure it using the [embedmongo-maven-plugin](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/embedmongo-maven-plugin) suggested on Flapdoodle's github read me. I tried, on my local Windows machine, to create a configuration that wouldn't download it (pom.xml code below) by creating a separate folder and telling it to look for a different folder, but it always tries to download it (does not look for a different folder).

I'm surely missing something here... Could you help me with that?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.root</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>My Project</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.joelittlejohn.embedmongo</groupId>
                <artifactId>embedmongo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <randomPort>true</randomPort>
                            <!-- optional, default is false, if true allocates a random port and overrides embedmongo.port -->

                            <databaseDirectory>C:/dev</databaseDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, default is a new dir in java.io.tmpdir -->

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm really not sure if I'm on the correct path - the `embedmongo-maven-plugin` does not seem to make any difference here... I could use another in-memory database solution, but Flapdoodle seems to be the simplest one, and that's why I'm currently trying with it.

-- Edit --

I've just tried the other suggested plugin, as below:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.syncleus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mongodb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <artifactDirectory>C:/dev/.embedmongo</artifactDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, set directory where MongoDB artifacts are stores,
                                 default is ~/.embedmongo -->


                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

However, it does not seem to work at all - even if I just add with no configurations (to run as default), it fails running locally (in an open network). I wonder if there are any other options...